# Java JSoup URL connection

Tags: java, jsoup

I've searched the web but could not find any help.

I have an URL like that looks like this

```
String url = "http://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/find.html?searchType=SALE&locationIdentifier=REGION%5E904&insId=3&radius=10.0&minPrice=&maxPrice=500000&minBedrooms=&maxBedrooms=&displayPropertyType=&maxDaysSinceAdded=&_includeSSTC=on&sortByPriceDescending=&primaryDisplayPropertyType=&secondaryDisplayPropertyType=&oldDisplayPropertyType=&oldPrimaryDisplayPropertyType=&newHome=&auction=false"
```

I have tried using `URLencoder.encode(url,"UTF-8")` but that didnt work.  Any ideas??

I'm using the following jsoup connection to try and crawl a webpage.

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 "
                + "(Windows NT 6.1)"
                + "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 "
                + "Safari/537.36").timeout(14000).followRedirects(false).
                ignoreContentType(true).get();
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "that didnt work" > how so?

Comment: it gives me >> org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=400, I tried https, I tried shortening the string and I tried pasting it in browser windows with no history

Comment: The URL is already urlencoded (`REGION%5E904` is `REGION^904`). Maybe you could try with the non-encoded form. If `JSoup` encodes the URL you gives him that would explain the problem, as it would produce `REGION%255E904` from `REGION%5E904`

Comment: `URLencoder.encode` did not give you an `HttpStatusException`. Problem solving in programming requires precision. Break the program into testable pieces. Output the URL before you connect and see whether it is as expected.

Comment: the decoded url using an online decoder is            http://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/find.html?searchType=SALE&locationIdentifier=REGION^904&insId=3&radius=10.0&minPrice=&maxPrice=500000&minBedrooms=&maxBedrooms=&displayPropertyType=&maxDaysSinceAdded=&_includeSSTC=on&sortByPriceDescending=&primaryDisplayPropertyType=&secondaryDisplayPropertyType=&oldDisplayPropertyType=&oldPrimaryDisplayPropertyType=&newHome=&auction=false

Comment: It's been solved.  How do I rate Aaron?  I needed an online application to decode it back into its plainest form away from UTF-8 and then it works.  Is there any explanation? Here is the link http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Comment: @Kevster Nobody expects a rating for a comment.

Comment: Yeah don't worry, you could upvote my comment if you want to but it really doesn't matter. Another alternative would be for me to answer your question so that you can accept it, but if you can with your current reputation, I suggest answering your own question and accepting your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For tricky urls I recommend getting the text using the following connection:

```
   String url = ""
   doc = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url).openStream(),  "ISO-8859-1", url);
```